# cannot run javascript program in terminal Mac

Tags: javascript, terminal, bbedit

I have made a JavaScript hello world program in BBEdit, and saved it as app.js. But when I'm trying to run the file in Terminal, I keep getting the error (syntax error near unexpected token `'Hello world'').

The code:

```
console.log("Hello world")
```

The odd thing is, when I type node and then `console.log("Hello world")` into terminal, it works, just not when placing app.js directly into terminal.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you running it?

Comment: Can you show us the Terminal command you're running?

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. I drag and drop "app.js" into terminal, and press enter. That's when I get the error.

Comment: I'm guessting that Terminal is attempting to run the JavaScript file as if it's a shell script.

Comment: Would that be something I could solve?

Comment: Do you have node installed? If so, you could run `node app.js`

Comment: yes, I have it installed. still makes no difference

Comment: when I do that, it says " command not found".

Comment: You will have to make sure that the node binary is in your path environment variable so it can be found by your system.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are attempting to run the JavaScript as if it was a shell script (dragging app.js on to Terminal).

What you will have to do instead is run the JavaScript file with Node.

Open Terminal and then type:

```
node app.js
```

Make sure you have the correct path to find your JavaScript file and it should work as you expect.

Make sure your system knows where node is, of course.